# Superimposing two image in IOS

Tags: ios, quartz-2d

I am creating a project which is kind of funny.

In my project what I am doing is with faces superimposed onto objects, say like I have Face Image on the background and i need to superimpose the object(Apple) on Face image , but it should not completely overlap but Eyes , mouth feature should be visible in object like the image in url

[image]

What I have done so far- Using AVFoundation I am detecting the face frame by frame.

Next i need to superimpose two image. Face image and object , but i need to reduce alpha component of face object so that it looks like apple talking .

Can somebody guide me or provide me with example code so i can achieve the same superimposing .

Edit 1:

Following is the code i am using to blend two images.

```
UIImage *bottomImage =[UIImage imageNamed:@"face.jpg"];
UIImage *image = imageview.image;

CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(imageview.frame.size.width, imageview.frame.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );

// Use existing opacity as is
[bottomImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height)];
// Apply supplied opacity
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.8];

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

imageview.image=newImage;
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

In above code I have superimposed two images reducing image alpha , but I don't need this . I want to reduce the specific portion say like i have three image , Left eyes, right eye and mouth , In object(apple) I need to reduce the alpha only this three image portion of object not the whole image .

Comment: Can you show the code where you already tried something?

Comment: I have updated code. but i need to reduce alpha with specific position of object not whole object.

Comment: So you want to have all areas in the face image to have zero alpha and the eyes and mouth to have a higher value? You need to detect the mouth and eye areas first. Use an external library or maybe implement some kind of feature detection yourself. Is this what you need?

Comment: I have detected the face features, now i need to change the alpha of the object (apple) according to the features area . Can you tell me how to reduce the alpha of the object according to the the area ?

Comment: Sounds like you need to solve image masking. There are many ways to achieve this... General approach: http://jeroendeleeuw.com/post/33638733049/how-to-mask-images-with-core-graphics-in-ios - extensive explanations: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-TPXREF101

Comment: Show the part how you pick up the face and then subsequently save the image might help analyze.

Answer (score 0):

If it is always a rectangular region, then you could draw in parts:

- divide the image into rects with the various alpha values that you want, and then draw those.

  - eg. if you want a rect (100, 100) of size (200, 200) with alpha=0.8
    and rest to be alpha=0.2, and width=height=400

> ```
> - draw rect, top rect:    (  0,   0) size (400, 100)
> - draw rect to the left:  (  0, 100) to   (100, 200)
> - draw rect to the right: (300, 100) to   (100, 200)
> - draw rect, bottom:      (  0, 300) to   (400, 100)
> ```

```
 ------------
 | top      |
 |          |
 |----------|
 |  | M |   |
 |L |   | R |
 |  |   |   |
 |----------|
 |  bottom  |
 |----------|
```

Draw all the parts separately, you can control the alpha separately for them now. M here is your "main" portion.

For non-rectangular ones you might want to construct a mask and use that to create the image.